# Converting a String into a datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string field like this..

```
2011-09-04 23:44:30.801000
```

and now I need to convert it to a datetime object in python so that I can calculate the difference between two datetime objects.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, which converts a string and date format into a `datetime.datetime` object.

The format fields (e.g., `%Y` denotes four-digit year) are specified [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s      = '2011-09-04 23:44:30.801000'
>>> format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
>>> date=datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format)
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 4, 23, 44, 30, 801000)
```

Comment: thanx :) i am using datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
this..

need to add another datetime...

Comment: @diamond In that case, it would have been very helpful to attach the  command along with its error message.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `datetime.datetime.strptime` would be the [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) libray. `dateutil` will allow you to do the same thing without the explicit formatting step:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> date_obj = parser.parse('2011-09-04 23:44:30.801000')
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 4, 23, 44, 30, 801000)
```

It's not a standard library module, but it is very handy for parsing date and time strings, especially if you don't have control over the format they come in.

One caveat if you install this library: version 1.5 is for `Python 2` and version 2.0 is for `Python 3`. `easy_install` and `pip` default to installing the 2.0 version, so you have to explicitly indicate `python-dateutil==1.5` if you are using `Python 2`.

Comment: +1 Nice idea, especially when you can't predict the exact format used.

Answer (score 0):

Use [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: I think it's `datetime.datetime.strptime()`

Answer (score 0):

```
# date string to datetime object
date_str = "2008-11-10 17:53:59"
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print repr(dt_obj)
```

Comment: I am running this exact code with version 3.3 and I keep getting an error that says "Does not match format" Any suggestions why?